# SQL Calculate fraction matching text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table with a status flag column. This can be 'OK', 'LOW', 'FAIL', ''`enter code here` or missing entirely.
I can get the number of log entries with:

```sql
SELECT count(status)
FROM senlogs
WHERE dtstamp>(now()-'1 hour'::INTERVAL)
```

And the number of 'OK' readings:

```sql
SELECT count(status)
FROM senlogs
WHERE dtstamp>(now()-'1 hour'::INTERVAL)
  AND status~'OK'
```

How can I calculate the fraction or percentage that are 'OK' in SQL atomically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation with `AVG()`:

```
SELECT AVG( (status = 'OK')::int )
FROM senlogs
WHERE dtstamp>(now()-'1 hour'::INTERVAL)
```